# sed - process line twice or rewind

Tags: sed

I'm editing data between two patterns, and I'm running into a problem where sed fails to match patterns that are back to back because the first pattern occurs in the same line as the second pattern.

The structure of my data looks something like this:

> **PATTERN2** Header **PATTERN1**
>    data
>    **DATA_1** ...
>    **DATA_2** ...
>    data
>    **PATTERN2** Header **PATTERN1**
>    data
>    **DATA_1** ...
>    **DATA_2** ...
>    data
>    data
>    data
>   **PATTERN2**
>   ...

and my sed command looks like this:

```
sed '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/ {s/DATA_[12]/SUB/g}' myFile
```

The number of lines between the patterns is dynamic and there is no other reliable pattern to search on other than what is printed in the Header line. The Header line is the only indicator of the end of a block of data.

Is there an opposite of 'n' to "rewind" one line?

thanks!

Comment: Append the new line to the buffer and apply your changes, then you can further process the previous line by regarding the part before the newline. -- Alternatively put the line in the hold space and swap it when you check the next line.

Comment: ...is this about XML or JSON or so?

Comment: Show your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: The substitution works fine, my problem is that since PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 occur on the same line, the second place where PATTERN1 occurs gets skipped since that line was included in the first match.

My intent is to perform the substitution between everywhere that PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 occur.

Comment: I Just gave the hold buffer a try ShellFish;  
  
`sed 'h; /PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/ {s/DATA_[12]/SUB/g;x}' myFile`  
  
the second occurrence was still skipped

Comment: Rename pattern1 when it occure together with pattern2, do the job, reverse renaming

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/PATTERN1/{:b;s/DATA_[12]/SUB/g;n;/PATTERN2/!bb;ba}' file
```

This uses a goto on encountering PATTERN2 to check for PATTERN1.